# Emailing a file from Enhanced FTP using Automation Studio

Tags: email, automation, automationstudio, ftp

I have an automation in place that exports data from a data extension and then uploads the file to our FTP account.

Is there was a process within Automation Studio to have that file emailed as an attachment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no default way to do so. However sending a file from the Import-folder of your Enhanced FTP is possible. Attaching csv-files isn't allowed for some reason, which is rather strange as this is the default format for exporting a data extension. Therefore further processing could be necessary in your case.

But basically adding a File Transfer Activity that moves the exported file from the Export to the Import directory on your Enhanced FTP would be necessary if the file doesn't reside in the Import directory already (which it will if you upload the file from an external system).

As soon as the file is placed in the correct folder you can add a Send Email activity that makes use of the `AttachFile` AMPscript function.

```
%%=AttachFile('FTP', 'nameOfTheFileOnFTP.xls', 'nameOfTheFileInEmail.xls')=%%
```

**Related documentation:**

- [AttachFile function reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/attachfile.htm)
- [File Transfer Activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_file_transfer_activity/)
- [Send Email Activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/send_email_activity/)

Comment: Thanks Markus! Just to confirm that I will need to create a new email with the above AMP script included. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct!